# .htaccess code to force twitterbot to use http instead of https

Tags: image, .htaccess, validation, twitter

Twitter card validator is having problems showing my image on

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://yourdomain.com/images/myimage.jpg">
```

because it can't handle https images using a shared SSL vs dedicated. Apparently the fix is to make the url http instead of https, and add code to your .htaccess file to tell twitterbot not to redirect to the https version

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Twitterbot [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

NOTE: My website currently doesn't have an .htaccess file. When I created one and added it to my website, the Twitter card validator worked and I could now see the image, however my actual website stopped working with this new .htaccess file. A message is shown that says:

*"This page isn’t working. www.yourdomain.com redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS."*

Is there a way to modify this to just include the twitter code and not mess with anything else?

Comment: RewriteConds are joined with an implicit AND unless the OR flag is used, so you are redirecting here if either the port is 80 and the host name is `yourdomain.com`, _OR_ if the host name is `www.yourdomain.com` and the UA is not the Twitterbot. The latter causes an endless redirect for anyone who’s not Twitter. If you don’t need to handle multiple domains differently here, then remove both those conditions checking on the host name; otherwise, combine them into a single one, that makes the `www.` part optional.

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand. I don't know much about .htaccess. This solution came from someone's blog but they had an existing .htaccess so I guess this doesn't work for me. I don't understand your directions. My SSL is from cloudflare so I think they handle the redirecting on their end.

Comment: _“My SSL is from cloudflare so I think they handle the redirecting on their end.”_ - then you probably can’t do much about it in the first place. If(!) they are redirecting everything from HTTP to HTTPS already, then your attempt to reverse that for a specific URL later, will most likely only lead to an endless redirect.

Comment: Yeah, so I see the http to https redirects are handled on cloudflare's end via your dashboard. You're supposed to enable it there for their ssl to work. So there's really no way for me to tell twitterbot to ignore that?